# in rails, how to return records as a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a simple database table called "Entries":

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.string :firstName
      t.string :lastName
      #etc.
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :entries
  end
end
```

How do I write a handler that will return the contents of the Entries table as a CSV file (ideally in a way that it will automatically open in Excel)?

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

  def getcsv
    @entries = Entry.find( :all )

    # ??? NOW WHAT ????

  end

end
```

Comment: At least in the more recent versions of Rails, you can also use `Entry.all` instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a plugin called FasterCSV that handles this wonderfully.

Comment: Note that ruby >= 1.9, FasterCSV is now the standard CSV library, and is just called CSV.

Comment: the key being `require 'csv'`, see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 91):

[FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html) is definitely the way to go, but if you want to serve it directly from your Rails app, you'll want to set up some response headers, too.

I keep a method around to set up the filename and necessary headers:

```
def render_csv(filename = nil)
  filename ||= params[:action]
  filename += '.csv'

  if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /msie/i
    headers['Pragma'] = 'public'
    headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain" 
    headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\"" 
    headers['Expires'] = "0" 
  else
    headers["Content-Type"] ||= 'text/csv'
    headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\"" 
  end

  render :layout => false
end
```

Using that makes it easy to have something like this in my controller:

```
respond_to do |wants|
  wants.csv do
    render_csv("users-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}")
  end
end
```

And have a view that looks like this: (`generate_csv` is from FasterCSV)

```
UserID,Email,Password,ActivationURL,Messages
<%= generate_csv do |csv|
  @users.each do |user|
    csv << [ user[:id], user[:email], user[:password], user[:url], user[:message] ]
  end
end %>
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was done until I saw your answer!  Thanks for the header details, I'll remember those in case I get into trouble with what I'm using so far.

Comment: As mentioned above, FasterCSV is just CSV in ruby 1.9 and up.  The gererate_csv method is now CSV.generate.

Comment: Adding .html_safe on the end of the generate_csv/CSV.generate block will make it so that any commas in the data are properly handled.  Without this call my csv file had a bunch of &quot;&quot; in it.

Comment: I've found myself referring to this answer over and over, so I finally bit the bullet and made a Rails 3 gem that provides a slightly modified version of the render_csv method provided here: https://github.com/spindance/rendered_csv

Answer (score 28):

I accepted (and voted up!) @Brian's answer, for first pointing me to FasterCSV.  Then when I googled to  find the gem, I also found a fairly complete example at [this wiki page](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoExportDataAsCSV).  Putting them together, I settled on the following code.

By the way, the command to install the gem is:
    sudo gem install fastercsv
(all lower case)

```
require 'fastercsv'

class EntriesController < ApplicationController

  def getcsv
      entries = Entry.find(:all)
      csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv| 
            csv << ["first","last"]
            entries.each do |e|
              csv << [e.firstName,e.lastName]
            end
          end
          send_data csv_string, :type => "text/plain", 
           :filename=>"entries.csv",
           :disposition => 'attachment'

  end


end
```

Comment: I would suggest moving the CSV generation into a view: that's more presentation logic than you'd normally want in a controller.

Comment: You may want to set the type to 'text/csv'. Otherwise, safari will save it as 'entries.csv.txt'

Answer (score 26):

Another way to do this without using FasterCSV:

Require ruby's csv library in an initializer file like config/initializers/dependencies.rb

```
require "csv"
```

As some background the following code is based off of [Ryan Bate's Advanced Search Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111) that creates a search resource. In my case the show method of the search resource will return the results of a previously saved search. It also responds to csv, and uses a view template to format the desired output.

```
  def show
    @advertiser_search = AdvertiserSearch.find(params[:id])
    @advertisers = @advertiser_search.search(params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.csv  # show.csv.erb
    end
  end
```

The show.csv.erb file looks like the following:

```
<%- headers = ["Id", "Name", "Account Number", "Publisher", "Product Name", "Status"] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<%- @advertiser_search.advertisers.each do |advertiser| -%>
<%- advertiser.subscriptions.each do |subscription| -%>
<%- row = [ advertiser.id,
            advertiser.name,
            advertiser.external_id,
            advertiser.publisher.name,
            publisher_product_name(subscription),
            subscription.state ] -%>
<%=   CSV.generate_line row %>
<%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

On the html version of the report page I have a link to export the report that the user is viewing. The following is the link_to that returns the csv version of the report:

```
<%= link_to "Export Report", formatted_advertiser_search_path(@advertiser_search, :csv) %>
```

Comment: Dont forget to use `<%= CSV.generate_line(row).html_safe %>` if you are using rails 3, to avoid escaping characters.

Comment: This solution works fine but I had to change the CSV.generate_line calls setting :row_sep to nil. This change removes unwanted blank lines from the response. Code:
`<%= CSV.generate_line row, {:row_sep => nil} %>`

Comment: To add to Wilson's comment, Heroku (cedar stack -beta) will insert blank lines into csv files unless you explicitly tell it not to with `:row_sep => nil`.

Comment: I also had to add a '-' at the end of the generate_line_headers. Otherwise there was a blank line after the header line.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look into the [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html) gem.

If all you need is excel support, you might also look into generating a xls directly. (See Spreadsheet::Excel)

```
gem install fastercsv
gem install spreadsheet-excel
```

I find these options good for opening the csv file in Windows Excel:

```
FasterCSV.generate(:col_sep => ";", :row_sep => "\r\n") { |csv| ... }
```

As for the ActiveRecord part, something like this would do:

```
CSV_FIELDS = %w[ title created_at etc ]
FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  Entry.all.map { |r| CSV_FIELDS.map { |m| r.send m }  }.each { |row| csv << row }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The following approached worked well for my case and causes the browser to open the appropriate application for the CSV type after downloading.

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv { return index_csv }
  end
end

def index_csv
  send_data(
    method_that_returns_csv_data(...),
    :type => 'text/csv',
    :filename => 'export.csv',
    :disposition => 'attachment'
  )
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Content-Type header in your response, then send the data. Content_Type: application/vnd.ms-excel should do the trick.

You may also want to set the Content-Disposition header so that it looks like an Excel document, and the browser picks a reasonable default file name; that's something like Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{suggested_name}.xls"

I suggest using the fastercsv ruby gem to generate your CSV, but there's also a builtin csv. The fastercsv sample code (from the gem's documentation) looks like this:

```
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
# ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that obscure Content-Type!  I'm not actually sure if it's going to be Excel in the end, but that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

try a nice gem to generate CSV from Rails
https://github.com/crafterm/comma

Comment: Good answer but to make it great, perhaps you could explain why this gem (as opposed to others)

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply wanting to get the csv database yourself from the console you can do so in a few lines

```
tags = [Model.column_names]
rows = tags + Model.all.map(&:attributes).map(&:to_a).map { |m| m.inject([]) { |data, pair| data << pair.last } }
File.open("ss.csv", "w") {|f| f.write(rows.inject([]) { |csv, row|  csv << CSV.generate_line(row) }.join(""))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CSV Shaper gem.

[https://github.com/paulspringett/csv_shaper](http://github.com/paulspringett/csv_shaper)

It has a nice DSL and works really well with Rails models. It also handles the response headers and allows filename customisation.