# rails 3, hosted @ heroku, can display CSV on browser... but how direct to 'save-as' dialog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export, savefiledialog

In my rails 3 app I use fastercsv to create a csv file to screen, works great now... but how do I instead have it open a dialog to save the file to the user's local system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this SO answer (the one with 19 upvotes, not the accepted answer): [in rails, how to return records as a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94502/in-rails-how-to-return-records-as-a-csv-file)

The key is sending the file with the `headers['Content-Disposition']`