# in rails, unable to override content-disposition filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-headers, chromium, fastercsv, content-disposition

I am using Rails 3.1.0.rc8 and Chromium 15.0.874.102.

I want to set the filename of a CSV download. I am following this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94626/614660), but find myself unable to modify the `filename` of the `Content-Disposition` header.

Here is my code:

```
module ActionController 
  module CSVHelper

    def render_csv options={}
      if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /msie/i
        headers['Pragma'] = "public"
        headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain"
        headers['Cache-Control'] = "no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
        headers['Expires'] = "0"
      else
        headers['Content-Type'] = "text/csv"
      end

      filename = generate_filename options.delete(:basename)
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{filename}"
    end

    def generate_filename basename=nil, suffix="csv"
      filename = basename || params[:action]
      filename << ".#{suffix}"
      filename
    end

  end
end
```

And in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv do
    render_csv(:basename => "my_filename")
    Rails.logger.debug "HEADERS: #{headers.to_s}"
  end
end
```

In my log:

```
[2011-11-28 12:25:49.611] DEBUG - HEADERS: {"Content-Type"=>"text/csv", "Content-Disposition"=>"attachment; filename=my_filename.csv"}
```

In Chromium network inspector tool, I see the following in my Response Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=index.csv
```

If I change the `Content-Type` to something like `foo/bar`, I see the change come through in my network inspector tool. No matter what I set the `filename` to, it remains `index.csv`.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: do you have the view correctly set up?

Comment: the view renders as expected, if that's what you mean; the content of the downloaded file looks like I want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Content-Disposition section of the appendices to the HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) the filename must be a *quoted string*:

> ```
>    filename-parm = "filename" "=" quoted-string
>    ...
> ```
>
> An example is
>
> ```
>    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
> ```

So you probably need to make the following change (note the quotation marks):

```ruby
headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
```

Comment: Note that if the filename itself can contain quotes, you'll need to escape them - `filename.gsub(/"/, '\\"')`

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't use `render` for this sort of content - I prefer to use `send_data`. Here's an example:

```
send_data data, :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => 'attachment; filename=my_file_name.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my team is using the [csv_builder](https://github.com/econsultancy/csv_builder) gem, which allows you to adjust the name of the downloaded file by setting `@filename` in the controller. Will still award correct answer to anyone who can explain why I was getting the behavior described in OP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are actually sending / rendering the output... Is that in a .csv.erb file or something? Or using csv_builder as other answer? That could be the trick.

I came up with the same thing rendering a .xlsx output. Once I had the file on disk, I could do this:

```
def example
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx do
      path = some_method_generating_xlsx_file
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.xlsx"
      render :text => File.binread(path), :content_type => XLSX_MIME_TYPE
    end
  end
end
```

in my controller, and it worked just fine. Perhaps the headers were being clobbered by the template rendering.