# Rails exporting to Excel first renders in browser, on F5 presents download to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a survey app, and I need to export the data to Excel. I added a `.xls` mime-type and I have a view called `results.xls.slim` that contains an html table.

My controller looks like this:

```
 # GET /survey_groups/1/results
  def results
    @survey_group = get_survey_group
    @survey = @survey_group.survey
    @questions = @survey.questions
    @members = @survey_group.members

    organisation = @survey_group.organisation

    respond_to do |format|
      # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627291/rails-excel-mime-type-how-to-change-default-filename
      format.xls { headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{ organisation.name } - Survey Group Results\""  }
    end
  end
```

The problem when I click on the link to export to Excel

```
= link_to('Excel', survey_results_path(@organisation.id, @survey_group.id, format: 'xls'))
```

the results first render in the browser (see the screenshot below). Only when I F5 do I get the downloadable file as expected.

[image]

In case anyone is wondering, Excel does render basic html and somehow converts it so you can still use formulas etc (which makes for very convenient exporting of tabular data with no interop libraries needed etc.).

I only want the results to be downloaded, not rendered in the browser.

Comment: Try removing format from your link..

Comment: @RailsGuy that made no difference

Comment: Please use the send_file method in your controller see this link http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file

Comment: @KiranKumara how do I use send_file with my scenario. The view first needs to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem is that I am using jQuery Pjax and needed to disable PJax for the export to Excel link.

Answer (score -1):

Please Follow this railscast [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

and try.

I hope this will helps

Comment: Answers should contain all relevant example code and explanations, not just link to another site.