# Exporting dataset as CSV not returning complete dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I'm currently working on a large surveying application which is currently in production on Heroku (Cedar, 4 web dynos, Crane PostgreSQL database). Due to time constraints, I have a Survey model, with the questions exposed through attr_accessible. I am looking to export the days results, which is generally 5000+ rows of data, with about 45 columns.

When I export the day's surveys (`Survey.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)`), using a combination of [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) and [this](http://pro.benjaminste.in/post/437368566/huge-csv-data-exports-in-rails), it prompts for download, downloads, but when I open it, I only have about 2/3 of the data. Sometimes it cuts off about midway through a row.

It seems like I'm hitting some sort of memory issue, or an issue sending everything to the Excel/CSV properly. I'm convinced it's because of data size, but I can't control that, I'm just trying to find the issue. Any ideas on how I can try to resolve this? It's pretty debilitating.

Here's the code in the survey model which handles the CSV/Excel writing:

```
  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.find_each do |survey|
        csv << survey.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Currently on the controller I format everything in a index.xls.erb.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Some debugging ideas: check the header for size, check for disconnects, timeouts, try accessing with `curl`, try running from Rails console, to pinpoint if it's an issue of transfer, buffering, library...

Comment: @Amadan - Thanks for the for the debug ideas. I'll give those a shot, see if I can add any more pieces to my puzzle.

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue, not memory, is it always at the same line the write ends ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue! After a bit of poking around, I switched from using a HTML formatted view/xls file to just doing a barebones CSV , formatted in a view, as referenced in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222698/886084). This worked perfectly. Thanks for the troubleshooting ideas everyone!